# How to cite an article from Arxiv using bibtex

Tags: bibtex, arxiv

This is a question about how to use bibtex to cite a preprint from Arxiv. Suppose I have:

```
@ARTICLE{BM:1999,
   AUTHOR  = {First, Author AND Second, Author},
   TITLE   = {The title of this article},
   YEAR    = {2035},
   JOURNAL = What exactly do I put here?,
   VOLUME  = {},
   NUMBER  = {},
   PAGES   = {}
}
```

Where exactly do I put the code of the article in arxiv? Suppose the code is arXiv:1234:5678v1

I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}  % (uses file "plain.bst")amsplain
\bibliography{myrefs}    % expects file "myrefs.bib"
```

**EDIT:**Actually there is a BibTeX entry that is `@unpublished` which is the one I am using. I didn't noticed and I put `@article` in the example above. It has fields: author, title, note, month, year and key. So the question is more about whether to put the arxiv code of the article in note or in key.

Comment: This seems rather off-topic to me: it's about AMS house style more than (La)TeX or BibTeX

Comment: A good start might be the following script I've just created: [automatically create BibTeX entry from arXiv](http://www.martin-thoma.de/arxiv.php) (and [hacky php source](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/8133254))

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's also worth mentioning Biblatex, which has proper support for eprints with all styles. For arXiv, specifically, you can use

```
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {0902.0885},
 primaryClass = {quant-ph},
```

for a new-style eprint, or

```
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
   eprint = {quant-ph/0401062},
```

for an old-style eprint.

Both entries were taken directly from the [NASA ADS](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/#abs/arXiv:0902.0885) database, clicking on "Export". The `journal` field you left empty, except of course if has actually been published elsewhere. As for the template, it depends on the style you are using. I use `@article` with the style `biblatex-phys`, and the formatting is good, but with the default style it produces crap if `journal` is empty. In this case you can use `@misc` and `@online`, with similar results. You should avoid `@unpublished`, however, as it hides the eprint number.

EDIT: Updated to take into account the comments.

Comment: I disagree that the formatting as `@article` is good. You get something of the form `... In: (2015)` if you omit the `journal` field, which looks strange...

Comment: Yeah the missing "in" is really odd.

Comment: Unfortunately arXiv itself is still using texlive 2011 which is completely incompatible with the version of biblatex in texlive 2016.

Comment: I would advise to use the `@misc` type, as it officially allows the fields `eprint`, `eprintclass`, and `eprinttype`, as opposed to `@unpublished`, and `@online`. `@article` requires `journaltitle`, as @Jonathan pointed out. See [biblatex documentation](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (_2.1 Entry Types_ and _3.12. Electronic Publishing Information_)

Comment: anyone else experience that archivePrefix in one bibtex entry makes the hidden links in the pdf ALL get prefixed by the value of archivePrefix (ie arxiv.org)? This is using apsrev-title.bst

Comment: Does not work in ACM template. There is a . followed by , - this indicates a missing field.

Answer (score 147):

This is what I do

1. Go to arXiv site: e.g. [math example](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9503002)
2. On the right, click "Export Bibtex Citation"
   [image]
3. Copy and paste the citation into your bibtex file. For the previous example, you will get the following output:

```
@article{Baez_1995,
    doi = {10.1063/1.531236},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1063%2F1.531236},
    year = 1995,
    month = {nov},
    publisher = {{AIP} Publishing},
    volume = {36},
    number = {11},
    pages = {6073--6105},
    author = {John C. Baez and James Dolan},
    title = {Higher-dimensional algebra and topological quantum field theory},
    journal = {Journal of Mathematical Physics}
}
```

5. (Optional) Check for the most common mistakes in automatically created bib entries [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch).

> Note: Not all the the papers of arxiv are cataloged as @articles, it would depend. This is [an example](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.11076) of @misc.

Comment: This is ridiculously useful, I wish I knew about this before...

Answer (score 16):

I usually leave `journal` blank, or put in the word "pre-print". The arXiv information I usually put in `note`, since the AMS styles ignore the `eprint` field. When I get less lazy I sometimes use, instead of the `@article` document type, `@misc`.

Comment: This more like what I was asking. Now, it would be good to know if this is standard and even more if AMS has some guideline in this case.

Comment: Actually there is a bibtex entry that is @unpublished which is the one I am using. I didn't noticed and I put @article in the example above. It has fields: author, title, note, month, year and key. So the question is more about whether to put the arxiv code of the article in note or in key.

Comment: Nevermind. Key is a field that is ignored and not printed, so it can not be there. Then I think it should be in NOTE as you said.

Comment: What exactly should be in the note field? The full URL or just the arXiv id?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: there is no "should", since I don't think it is standardized. But I generally just put the arXiv id such as `arXiv:gr-qc/XXXXXXX` or `arXiv:XXXX.XXXX` Remember, absent an actual style guide from a journal, the main goal of the bibliography is to make the references findable by readers. The arXiv id (properly formatted) is sufficient to uniquely identify a pre-print, so it is generally good enough.

Answer (score 15):

General arXiv citations are explained [in the arXiv help](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles). The correct citation format depends on whether it is an "old style" arXiv reference (eg arXiv:hep-ph/9609357) or "new style" (eg arXiv:0807.2882 [cond-mat.mes-hall]).

The REVTeX4.1 bibstyles also support arXiv references.

AMS styles, I can't help....

Comment: +1 for `eprint`, that's as much of a standard as I've ever seen. If the AMS styles don't use it, then that's an AMS-specific issue. You can modify the Bibtex style to include the eprint field if it's important to you.

Comment: Neither `eprint` nor `url` are standard fields in the current BibTeX. You can't hardly fault a style for not implementing a non-standard field. (Though I thought I heard a rumour here that the next version of BibTeX will have proper support of electronic documents.)

Comment: Just a comment on David Zaskavsky's comment: There is a lovely little script called `urlbst` that adds support for the `eprint` and `url` fields (and various other kinds of web link e.g. DOI's and PubMed) to an existing bst file. It works fine on the AMS styles.

Answer (score 10):

DBLP, which generally produces good BibTeX files, formats an archive entry as:

```
@article{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1207-0016,
  author    = {Ruchen Duan Yingbin Liang},
  title     = {Bounds and Capacity Theorems for Cognitive Interference
               Channels with State},
  journal   = {CoRR},
  volume    = {abs/1207.0016},
  year      = {2012},
  ee        = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0016},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

(http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/journals/corr/abs-1207-0016)

Comment: This format does not follow the guideline given on [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/references), and I won't understand the reference personally if the URL is not shown.

Comment: The output is not correct since CoRR does not include the stat, math, physics, econ, and other fields in the arXiv.

Comment: This helped me! The sample BibTeX from arXiv itself was largely ignored by natbib: all I could get printed was title, author names, and years.  Switched to the DLPB-generated version and now everything prints, including arXiv numbers and URL.

Answer (score 3):

For compiling my list of publications I use the bibtex entry that [Spires](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/hep/) provides for each record. You can search the author and date to find the Spires entry.

Answer (score 1):

`@misc` is the best solution. Just specify `archivePrefix="arXiv"`, and the `eprint` id, as in Mateus's answer.

`@article` shows a blank `In:` field, and `@unpublished` doesn't show an arXiv id, but `@misc` shows author, title, year, and arXiv id.

Answer (score 0):

A Chrome extension called 'Librarian' from Fermat’s Library can extract citation in BibTeX format directly from arXiv:

https://fermatslibrary.com/librarian

Comment: This Chrome extension doesn't appear to be available anymore. (the link from that website goes nowhere, and Chrome web store returns no results when searching for it)

Comment: The link still works for me

Comment: Website works, but cannot download the extension. Did you try downloading?