# What should an entry for arXiv entries look like for biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, arxiv

The tool I'm using to manage references ([Papers](http://www.mekentosj.com/papers/mac) for OS X; [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120427115002/http://www.mekentosj.com/papers/mac)) doesn't seem to be capable of properly exporting [*arXiv*](https://arxiv.org/) entries for use with `biblatex`. What is the correct `biblatex` format for an *arXiv* entry?

For example, Papers generates items like

```
@article{Altshuler2002,
    author = {Altshuler, B},
    title = {{Calculation of the observationally small cosmological constant in the model of six-dimensional}},
    journal = {Arxiv preprint hep-th},
    year = {2002},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0206225}}

@article{Acemoglu2010,
    author = {Acemoglu, Daron and Como, Giacomo and Fagnani, Fabio and Ozdaglar, Asuman},
    title = {{Opinion fluctuations and disagreement in social networks}},
    journal = {arXiv.org},
    year = {2010},
    volume = {cs.SI},
    month = sep,
    rating = {0},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2653v1}}
```

which, [as near as I can tell](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/), should actually look like

```
@eprint{Altshuler2002,
    eprinttype={arxiv}, 
    eprint = "hep-th/0206225"
    author = {Altshuler, B},
    title = {{Calculation of the observationally small cosmological constant in the model of six-dimensional}},
    year = {2002},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0206225}}

@eprint{Acemoglu2010,
    eprinttype={arxiv}, 
    eprint = "1009.2653v1",
    primaryClass = "cs.SI",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    author = {Acemoglu, Daron and Como, Giacomo and Fagnani, Fabio and Ozdaglar, Asuman},
    title = {{Opinion fluctuations and disagreement in social networks}},
    year = {2010},
    month = sep,
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2653v1}}
```

in order to take full advantage of `biblatex`.

Are these the correct BibLaTeX forms for *arXiv* entries? I'm having trouble reconciling [related answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3833/7844) I find here, the output from [online resources](https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=Calculation%20of%20the%20observationally%20small%20cosmological%20constant%20in%20the%20model%20of%20six-dimensional) for generating BibTeX, and the [arXiv spec](https://arxiv.org/help/hypertex/bibstyles/)—not to mention the seemingly *arXiv*-unaware output (above) that I get from Papers (or, for that matter, JabRef or Zotero).

Comment: You don't need to use the `url` field - just `eprinttype`, `eprint` and for articles with a subject classification `eprintclass` (or its alias `primaryclass`). These fields are described in section 3.10.7 of the manual. The `biblatex-examples.bib` file from the documentation also has a number of entries from arXiv.

Comment: @Audrey Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: You might be interested in the following script I've just created: [automatically create BibTeX entry from arXiv](http://www.martin-thoma.de/arxiv.php) (and [hacky php source](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/8133254))

Comment: Oh, and I've just found [DBLP](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/), which gives a BibTeX-export.

Comment: Should not the title say ‘BibLaTeX’ instead of ‘BibTeX’? Or are the answers the same?

Comment: @Mankka: It's 'BibTeX', isn't it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no `eprint` entry type. arXiv articles can be entered as `article` or `online` types. Article identifiers are represented by the `eprinttype` and `eprint` fields. Any arXiv subject classification should be entered in `eprintclass` or its alias `primaryclass`. The `url` field is unnecessary as standard styles generate a link to the article from its identifiers.

Here are some (partial) arXiv entries from the documentation.

```
@Article{baez/article,
  author      = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},
  title       = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2-Groups},
  journaltitle= {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  volume      = {12},
  version     = {3},
  date        = {2004},
  pages       = {423--491},
  urldate     = {2006-10-01},
  eprinttype  = {arxiv},
  eprint      = {math/0307200v3}
}
@Online{baez/online,
  hyphenation = {american},
  author      = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},
  title       = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2-Groups},
  version     = {3},
  date        = {2004-10-27},
  eprinttype  = {arxiv},
  eprint      = {math/0307200v3}
}
@Online{wassenberg,
  hyphenation = {american},
  author      = {Wassenberg, Jan and Sanders, Peter},
  title       = {Faster Radix Sort via Virtual Memory and Write-Combining},
  version     = {1},
  date        = {2010-08-17},
  eprinttype  = {arxiv},
  eprintclass = {cs.DS},
  eprint      = {1008.2849v1}
}
```

Annotations and additional examples can be found in the `biblatex-examples.bib` file. Further details can be found in section 3.10.7 of the biblatex manual.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I realize now my question was a bit naive: I really didn't understand how `eprint` was used. But, in my defense, Papers is partly at fault. The app, for reasons known only to its "designers", discards all kinds of information that it has and used to generate e-prints, and instead transforms everything into a plain `article` (even though it has fields in its database for things like the arXiv, and PubMed IDs, and the arXiv category). Some tricks with BBEdit and Regex repair the damage, but it's still puzzling why Papers would behave the way it does.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Probably to support bibtex. The bibtex translator for Zotero could probably be configured to output eprint fields for arXiv, pubmed, etc.

Comment: BibTeX with babplain-fl doesn't understand those entries, sorry (Latest texlive on Fedora 25).