# Biblatex inserts dead link when citing an eprint

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, links

I'm trying to cite an [eprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eprint) with `biblatex`. Back in my BibTeX days, I used `@misc` for that, but with `biblatex`'s additional entry types it appears that `@online` is better suited for this purpose.

In addition, I use the `hyperref` package to insert links in my document at various places, including links to online documents in my bibliography, such as this eprint.

Back in my BibTeX days I would have used this:

```
@misc{foo,
  author       = {David Pointcheval and Olivier Sanders},
  title        = {Short Randomizable Signatures},
  year         = {2015},
  month        = jun,
  howpublished = {Cryptology ePrint Archive, Report 2015/525},
  note         = {\url{http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/525}},
}
```

Now with `biblatex`, I tried to improve this like so:

```
@online{foo,
  author     = {David Pointcheval and Olivier Sanders},
  title      = {Short Randomizable Signatures},
  year       = 2015,
  month      = jun,
  eprinttype = {Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  eprint     = {2015/525},
  url        = {https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/525}
}
```

[image]

The problem is that there are now *two* hyperlinks. The first stems from the `eprint` field (`2012/525`) and the second from the `url` field (`https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/185`). The second one works perfectly fine and looks as intended, but the first one appears to link to the local file `2012/525` relative to the directory which contains the PDF itself, which is of course nonsense. Such a file does not exist and accordingly I get an error message when I try to click on the link.

How can I remove this dead link? As a side question, what is the original intent of hyperlinking the `eprint` field to a local file? I cannot see any practical use for this.

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{foo,
  author     = {David Pointcheval and Olivier Sanders},
  title      = {Short Randomizable Signatures},
  year       = 2015,
  month      = jun,
  eprinttype = {Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  eprint     = {2015/525},
  url        = {https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/525}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: to your side question: it merely interprets the `eprint` field as an url and your system assumes from the form of the link that it is a _relative link_ to a local file. I'm assuming you do not want the obvious solution (i.e. putting the url into the eprint field and changing eprinttype to "Cryptology .... (2015/525)" or sth like that)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of the `eprint` field is that it provides the unique part of some electronic reference, with the type supplying the 'setup'. In a case where the type is unknown, `bibaltex` assumes the epint ID contains the full URL, so simply makes it into a hyperlink. The `hyperref` package interprets links lacking `http` or similar as local ones, hence the outcome you see.

What you need to do is tell `biblatex` about the eprint type. I'd give it a one-word name, for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:iacr}{%
  \href{https://eprint.iacr.org/#1}{Cryptology ePrint Archive: #1}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{foo,
  author     = {David Pointcheval and Olivier Sanders},
  title      = {Short Randomizable Signatures},
  year       = 2015,
  month      = jun,
  eprinttype = {iacr},
  eprint     = {2015/525},
  url        = {https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/525}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I'd probably remove the URL field here as it's just the eprint data repeated (in the same way I'd have a DOI field not a link for a publisher article). You could though set up to clear the URL if it matches the eprint data.

Comment: Thanks and you're right about removing the URL field. One thing is still bugging me, though: If I do remove the URL field, then `biber --validate_datamodel` complains about the missing *mandatory* field `url` for `@online` entries. This makes me feel like although this solution does work well, it is not the *intended* way to cite eprints. On the other hand, the `biblatex-examples.bib` provided with BibLaTeX itself also contains an `@online` entry `baez/online` which lacks the `url` field (so, even citing directly from `biblatex-examples.bib` produces this warning!) Not so mandatory after all?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa My understanding of the data model is that an article which is online-only goes down as `@article` not `@online`: the latter is for things like websites.

Comment: I thought about this possibility too, but the problem is that `@article` in turn requires a `journaltitle` which does not make sense in this context (because it is an online database of papers, not a journal). So then, biber will complain about a missing journal title instead of a missing URL... Funny. [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50039/42810) cites a few examples from `biblatex-examples.bib` to cite arXiv eprints using both `@article` and `@online`, but a journal title is not applicable in my case and the url field is missing from those examples too.

Comment: Well, I guess that `@online` and `@article` can both be used for eprints (depending on the situation), and that the `url` field for `@online` is in fact circumstancially *not* necessary. In that sense, `biber --validate_datamodel` is perhaps too strict here. This is also what @Audrey said in the answer mentioned in my previous comment: "arXiv articles can be entered as article or online types. (...) The url field is unnecessary as standard styles generate a link to the article from its identifiers." That makes sense, although the warning is slightly annoying, but I guess I can live with it. ;)