# some changes in biblatex authoryear style

Tags: biblatex, natbib, texmaker

It took me nearly this entire day to figure out natbib might not be the way to go for my masters thesis. So now I finally switched to Biblatex. However there are still some things I can't figure out. I produce my bibfile with citavi.

- I got the editor displayed as 'Hrsg. von {editor}' and want to change that to 'Hrsg.: {editor}' for @book and @booklets
- Is there a way of printing URLDATESs for internet references (@booklets)?
  desired output would be :
  {author} ({year}). {title}. Hrsg.: {editor}. {url}. last accessed: {urldate}

this is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
            natbib=true, 
            backend=biber, 
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=9,
            uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur_Citavi.bib} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % German
\setlength\bibitemsep{.5\baselineskip}

% et al instead u.a.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},            
}

% Lastname, F.
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
   \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
   {\namepartfamily}
   {\namepartgiveni}
   {\namepartprefix}
   {\namepartsuffix}%
}%


% Comma between Journal and Volume
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
   \usebibmacro{journal}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%<--da
   \iffieldundef{series}
   {}
   {\newunit
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit{\addspace}}%
   \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
   \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{issue}%
   \newunit}




\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@booklet{copeland.,
 abstract = {Artificial intelligence, the ability of a computer or computer-controlled robot to perform tasks commonly associated with intelligent beings. The term is frequently applied to the project of developing systems with the ability to reason, discover meaning, generalize, or learn from past experiences.},
 author = {Copeland, B. J.},
 editor = {{Encyclopaedia Britannia}, Inc.},
 year = {2019},
 title = {Artificial Intelligence},
 howpublished = {\url{https://www.britannica.com/technology/artificial-intelligence}},
 urldate = {26.07.2019}
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]
How do I change the display of the editor field for @books and @booklets in general into 'Hrsg.: {editor}'?

Comment: The arXiv is not the `editor` (*Herausgeber*) of a paper it at all it might be seen as a `publisher` (Verlag?), but usually it is not seen as that either. `@book` is also not the right entry type here, since we are talking about a paper of nine pages. For arXiv papers that have not been published in a journal yet, `@online` would be a more appropriate entry type. Good examples for arXiv papers in `biblatex` can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49757/35864

Comment: Yeah I know its not actually a book, that was only some workaround to have the year for such papers included.

Comment: Thanks for the catch I removed Arxiv from the editor field. Still how can I adjust the display of that editor field for other books? The issue of 'Hrsg.' is the same for them

Comment: Can you please add a relevant example entry for that issue and explain the desired output with the example.

Comment: I changed the example and tried to explain the desired output a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change ‘Hrsg. von’ to ‘Hrsg.:’ you need to redefine the `byeditor` string.

The `urldate` is not appearing because you have used the wrong format. Date fields in `biblatex` need to be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. The output format is taken care of by localisation settings. The format of the `urldate` defaults to:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
```

So you could redefine this and/or redefine the `urlseen` string to match what you want.

And you probably want `editor = {{Encyclopaedia Britannia, Inc.}}` instead of
`editor = {{Encyclopaedia Britannia}, Inc.}` to avoid ‘Inc.‘ being treated as a family name.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
            natbib=true, 
            backend=biber, 
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=9,
            uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % German
\setlength\bibitemsep{.5\baselineskip}

% et al instead u.a.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
   andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
   byeditor  = {Hrsg\adddot\addcolon},
}

% Lastname, F.
\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
   \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
   {\namepartfamily}
   {\namepartgiveni}
   {\namepartprefix}
   {\namepartsuffix}%
}%


% Comma between Journal and Volume
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
   \usebibmacro{journal}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%<--da
   \iffieldundef{series}
   {}
   {\newunit
      \printfield{series}%
      \setunit{\addspace}}%
   \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
   \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{issue}%
   \newunit}




\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@booklet{copeland.,
 abstract = {Artificial intelligence, the ability of a computer or computer-controlled robot to perform tasks commonly associated with intelligent beings. The term is frequently applied to the project of developing systems with the ability to reason, discover meaning, generalize, or learn from past experiences.},
 author = {Copeland, B. J.},
 editor = {{Encyclopaedia Britannia, Inc.}},
 year = {2019},
 title = {Artificial Intelligence},
 howpublished = {\url{https://www.britannica.com/technology/artificial-intelligence}},
 urldate = {2019-07-26}
}


\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

For what it's worth, I'd set your bib entries up like this:

```
@online{copeland2019,
  author = {Copeland, B. J.},
  title = {Artificial intelligence},
  eprinttype = {Encyclopædia Britannica},
  date = {2019-05-09},
  eprint = {https://www.britannica.com/technology/artificial-intelligence},
  urldate = {2019-08-29}
}
@online{aunkofer2019,
  author = {Aunkofer, Benjamin},
  title = {Machine Learning vs Deep Learning},
  subtitle = {Wo liegt der Unterschied?},
  eprinttype = {Data Science Blog},
  date = {2018-05-14},
  eprint = {https://data-science-blog.com/blog/2018/05/14/machine-learning-vs-deep-learning-wo-liegt-der-unterschied/},
  urldate = {2019-08-29}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right the date format was wrong because I was exporting my bibfile from citavi via Bibtex. So now that works and also the 'Hrsg.:' adjustment! 
Online sources are now labeled online instead booklet. However now the url is missing, format in bibfile is still  howpublished = {\url{https://data-science-blog.com/blog/2018/05/14/machine-learning-vs-deep-learning-wo-liegt-der-unterschied/}},
 where I tried all combinations of url/howpubliched and including/excluding \url
How can I include the url back in?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. These should all use the `online` entry type really. You should use the `url` field directly (there is no `howpublished` field in `online` entry types) and adjust the `url` field format to suit. The default is: `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}`. Also, 'Encyclopedia Britannica, Inc.' isn't really the editor. I'd put it in `organization` or `note` or `eprinttype` and create a custom format for this kind of `eprint`.

Comment: Thank you your set up of the bib entries  finally solved my issue. The solution was to export my url as 'eprint' and not 'url' and also to excluse \usepackage{url}.
So thanks a lot that really helped, now I can finally concentrate on writing my thesis :)