# arxiv citation function

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, arxiv

Suppose I have a bibliography entry that looks like this (I'm using `biblatex`):

```
@article{foo,
  author = {A. Author},
  title = {Super article},
  archivePrefix = "arXiv",
  eprint        = "3301.1234",
  primaryClass  = "hep-ex"
}
```

I would like to create a command `\arxiv`, that I could use like
`\arxiv{foo}`, that would print

```
[1][arXiv:3301.1234]
```

where `[1]` would be the same a what `\cite` does, and the second part would link to the arXiv page for the article, e.g. `http://arxiv.org/abs/3301.1234`.

Can this be done? I want this so I can cite arXiv papers in beamer, and if somebody (or I later) pulls apart the slides, the citation is useful even without the bibliography slides.

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't be using the `@article` entry type for an arxiv-published piece. For one, it has neither a `journal` nor a `year` field. Consider using the `@misc` entry type instead.

Comment: `@online` would also be perfectly fine, cf. `biblatex-example.bib`'s `baez/online`.

Comment: @Mico an arXiv paper has the year (it's even part of its ID together with the month), for the journal usually something like "ArXiv e-prints" is usually employed, this is what NASA ADS Database does.

Comment: In relation of the comment by @Mico, see [How to cite an article from Arxiv using bibtex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3833/31685)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define `\arxivcite`. It is a normal `\cite` and additionally prints the `eprint` information if available

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\arxivcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{eprint}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

---

For `numeric-comp`, try

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:cite:arxiv}{%
  arXiv\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
       \nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{cite:eprint}{%
  \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
    {\printfield{eprint}}
    {\printfield[eprint:cite:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\arxivcite}
  {}
  {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \usebibmacro{prenote}%
     \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelnumber}}%
     \usebibmacro{postnote}}%
   \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite:eprint}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
```

which disables any `-comp` features for this particular command. You will have to have a `\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:cite:<type>}` for every `eprint` type you intend to use.

Comment: arXiv [runs TeX Live 2011](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive), you must be sure this solution is compatible with such an old distribution.

Comment: @giordano Where in the question does it say that the solution needs to run on the arXiv systems? The solution does not employ any fancy commands as you can see, so I'm quite confident it works with a fairly wide range of older `biblatex` versions. Whether the one included in TeX live 2011 is amongst those I cannot say with certainty; I just had a look at `biblatex` 1.0 dated November 2010 however and am fairly optimistic that it will actually do the right thing there and with all newer versions.

Comment: Indeed I gave it fro granted that it was needed for arXiv, sorry, my fault.  I was just asking whether `\DeclareCiteCommand` was available in earlier version of the package.

Comment: @giordano `\DeclareCiteCommand` is one of the basic commands `biblatex` provides and has been available at least since version 1.0. I would suspect it was available in all official releases of `biblatex`, but that I cannot say with certainty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm getting `! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite' undefined.`

Comment: @SU3 What bibliography style are you using. I naturally assumed you were using `numeric`. Please show a full MWE of your problem.

Comment: I was using `numeric-comp`. Your example works when I switch to `numeric`. However, the formatting options seem to be rather limited as eprint macro produces the full string. Your command's output look approximately like this: `[1. arXiv: 1408.7084 (hep-ex)]` with `1408.7084 (hep-ex)` linked. I would like for formatting to be more flexible. For example `[1][arXiv:1408.7084]` with the whole string in the second pair of brackets linked and using smaller font. I looked up biblatex `\printfield`, but I couldn't find ones that print parts of what `\usebibmacro{eprint}` prints.

Comment: @SU3 With `numeric-comp` things get more complicated (and the macro is not `cite`), what if you cite two keys both with arXiv identifiers, do you want "[1][arXiv:1408.7084][2][arXiv:1408.7085]"? Getting things outside the brackets is not always that easy, what about postnotes or prenotes do they go in the first or second set of brackets or outside entirely? You can modify the `eprint:arxiv` field format.

Comment: @moewe Using your second example, I was able to produce what I wanted. Thanks! The only problem is that I get `! Undefined control sequence.` for `\abx@arxivpath`.

Comment: @SU3 Ah, yes, I forgot the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` bit. The code should now work together with `hyperref`.