# how to cite arXiv articles with new bibtex format

Tags: bibtex, arxiv

I am wondering what the recommended best way to cite [arXiv](http://www.arXiv.org) preprints using bibtex is.  It seems they have recently changed their auto-generated bibtex, and I would like to know what the best practice is, or if it's safe to just copy the autogenerated bibtex from "Export Bibtex Citation" link on arXiv (as recommended in for example this previous SE thread: [How to cite an article from Arxiv using bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3833/how-to-cite-an-article-from-arxiv-using-bibtex)).

Until recently, the autogenerated bibtex entry you would get by clicking "Export Bibtex Citation" would be in the following format, using `archivePrefix`, `eprint`, and `primaryClass` fields:

```
@misc{arxiv:1907.10597-oldformat,
    author = {Roy Schwartz and Jesse Dodge and Noah A. Smith and Oren Etzioni},
    title = {Green AI},
    archiveprefix = {arXiv},
    eprint = {1907.10597},
    primaryclass = {cs.CY},
    year = {2019}}
```

now it [includes a DOI](https://blog.arxiv.org/2022/02/17/new-arxiv-articles-are-now-automatically-assigned-dois/) and URL, but does not include those `archivePrefix`, `eprint`, and `primaryClass` fields. **EDIT: This was the result of a bug, and is no longer true. See answer.**

```
@misc{arxiv:1907.10597-newformat,
  author = {Schwartz, Roy and Dodge, Jesse and Smith, Noah A. and Etzioni, Oren},
  title = {Green AI},
  doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.1907.10597},
  url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10597},
  publisher = {arXiv},
  year = {2019}}
```

The old format made it easy to define a bibliography style to include the eprint code `arXiv: 1907.10597 [cs.CY]` in the reference, like (as implemented in biblatex for example the `bibstyle=authoryear` style):

> Schwartz, Roy et al. (2019). Green AI. arXiv: 1907.10597 [cs.CY].

as [recommended in the arXiv FAQ](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/references).

The new style doesn't contain the eprint field, so it's harder to do this (and default bibstyles will just include the doi and or url instead).

I realize this is just a question of how arXiv chooses to format their autogenerated bibtex entries, but given how prevalent these are, I wonder if there is some recommendation people have for the 'right' way to cite eprints (since they have DOIs now, should I not even want to include the eprint number, as it was in the old way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, this is a bug in arXiv's abstract rendering and not to be taken as a new format requirement for how we're exporting the bibtex citations. This has been addressed, returning to our own bibtex output when no DOI is provided.

All arXiv-ids contain a bibtex output available from the `/bibtex/` url construction. Using your example of arXiv:1907.10597, the bibtex url would be https://arxiv.org/bibtex/1907.10597, which still provides the formatting expected.

The logic behind what is supposed to occur is that when there is a user-provided DOI, arXiv will fetch the data from Crossref and display that as the bibtex export. Absent that user-provided data, we display the arXiv-produced bibtex. It's on our radar to add the `eprint` element into the DataCite sets that are getting pushed to Crossref, but the timeline for that work is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So iiuc, there are currently two options: (1) if one wants the version with the `archivePrefix` field they should use the /bibtex/ url construction, and (2) if one wants the doi version one should use the “Export Bibtex Citation” button. But ideally (2) should fall back on (1) unless there’s a user-provided DOI, but that currently doesn’t happen because of a bug?

Comment: Oh, I see the bug has been addressed, and my comment is no longer relevant!

Comment: Right. You can click the "export citation" in either case (you'll just get whatever Crossref thinks the citation should appear as (if there's a provided DOI), or ours if there's none provided). If you always want the arXiv one, you can use the bibtex url construction. In the future there may be a selector which allows you to choose between the two, but with the major infrastructure changes occurring this year, such an enhancement is unlikely to be addressed in the short-term.

Comment: Okay, great.  This is very useful to know.   I like the "if DOI then use Crossref, else use arXiv format" way of behaving.